# IOS 8 beta: how to use the Bug Reporter app

Tags: ios, ios8

I have upgraded my iPhone to IOS 8 beta 1 at the first place. I am glad that Apple added the Bug Reporter App in the beta version. But I  can't understand how to use it. When I launched the reporter, it asked me to enter my Apple ID and password. But I didn't find any login/submit button there...

Did I missed anything over there? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When keyboard appears, just click "Go" Button